# Battery Health for my Experiment?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I need to design and carry out an experiment to graduate from my high school. I decided to research the battery health of lithium-ion batteries because I've heard that if you let them discharge to 0% it will worsen the battery life.

My physics supervisor told me that I should think about creating a set-up to test the experiment. My first question would be, **what kind of equipment would I need to test this effect?** I'm guessing it would be something that could discharge the battery but I'm not sure what it's called.

If there is a device that can test this phenomenon my second question would then be **what would be my independent variable and dependent variable for the experiment?**

I had thought that the independent variable would just be how much I have discharged the battery and the dependent variable the capacity of the battery.

I'm a bit unsure if I need to tweak this a bit because my physics supervisor said that I should research the actual scientific names for the variables.

He also mentioned something about how I will eventually need to talk about hysteresis in my paper.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should check the many questions on here for battery state of charge. And you should have done that BEFORE choosing your graduation experiment...

Comment: How could've I known what to look for if I didn't know the terms to use? Would state of charge be the IV or DV?

Comment: see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/118161/152903

Comment: A lithium cell, even discharged to it's minimum allowed charge may have a life of 500 or more cycles. Since you want to measure the effect of discharge on lifetime, you do not want to discharge overly rapidly as that would be a confounding variable. Thus the time required to measure this discharge will be long. Since this is for your graduation, you don't want a long experiment. I suggest, instead of measuring lifetime, you measure the effect of discharge on cell _capacity_, i.e. milliamp-hours. I would also "overdischarge", to speed things up.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. So if the dependent variable is cell capacity then what would be the independent variable? You mention the discharge but could you clarify? What would I be changing about the discharge and is there a name for this?

Comment: By over-discharge, I mean discharging to open-circuit voltage of 2.5V or less. A typical DW01 battery protection IC will discharge to 2.5V _under load_. This will bounce back after the load is removed. i.e. open-circuit voltage will be above 2.5V.  If you need help with a circuit to discharge to a given level see for example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/694010/268467.

Comment: See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/692927/268467 for more detail regarding undervoltage disconnect circuit.

Answer (score 0):

> what kind of equipment

A Li-ion battery tester. [For example](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004913553454.html).

> what would be my independent variable and dependent variable for the experiment?

- Test 2 new cells, confirm they are identical (capacity and resistance)
- Charge one cell to 50 %, discharge the other to 0 %
- Wait 1 week
- Test the cells again
- Repeat for 8 weeks (50 % and 0 %, 1 week wait)
- After 2 months, plot the capacity and resistance of each cell over time